# How to set download speed limit restriction without using router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista, internet-sharing

I have a 1Mbps broadband internet connection. I am sharing this on my PC by using Windows Connection Sharing, so that my roommate can also access the internet. I want to set a speed limit of 500Kbps on both the PCs, so that each one gets his fair share.

I'm using Windows Vista, and my friend is using Windows 7.

Is this possible in Windows (or Linux)? Third-party freeware is fine.

Comment: You can use [NetLimiter 3](http://www.netlimiter.com/featurelistnl3.php) to limit your bandwidth: `"You can use NetLimiter 3 to set download or upload transfer rate limits for applications, connectionsand filters. With limits you can easily manage your internet connection's bandwidth (bandwidth shaper) and share it among all applications running on your computer"`. However, you need NetLimiter 3 Lite (or Pro) for this feature, which is not free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation is to use [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).  I've used this in the past with great success.

However, this won't stop you or your roommate from simply removing the limit whenever you feel like it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [NAT32](http://v2.nat32.com/index.html) to share internet. It has speed limiter too.

Answer (score 1):

I know a while back I had found a proxy software for web dev that had that feature. heres a link to some. [proxy list](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/65793)  it is very easy to do in linux or if you set up a full blown proxy like squid. both of you could use the squid proxy for antivirus scanning of incomming downloads as well as bandwidth sharing.