# How to limit download speed of a task?

Tags: windows, internet, download

I started GTA 5, now the task "GTAVLauncher.exe" tries to download 1 GB update from the internet, but it takes the whole bandwith.

Is there a way to limit the download speed of this task?
I already tried [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/), this worked fine, but unfortunattely it was only a test version and i can't efford it.

So is there a free method to limit the download speed of a task?

Comment: NetBalancer should do the trick. the free version can monitor up to 3 tasks at once. check http://superuser.com/questions/135719/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs

Comment: Thank you, this software was exactly what i was searching for

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, not a duplicate. I was asking for a free method to limit the bandwith, the answers only show solutions which you have to pay for.

Answer (score 1):

After a few Google seaches I found many free [alternatives](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=netlimiter+alternative) for NetLimiter.

---

Also, is it possible that your NetLimiter has destroyed your internet connection settings of your os. It's very unusual that one download task takes the whole bandwith in windows.

Therefore, first of all I would follow [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/configure-reservable-bandwidth-settings-windows) instruction which shows you how to set (or repair) the bandwith settings in windows. A few other methods are [here](http://computerstepbystep.com/limit-the-maximum-network-bandwidth-for-bits-background-transfers.html).

---

**Possible/ related answers/ questions:**

- [How can I limit bandwidth of other programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs)
- [Windows command line utility to control network bandwidth](https://superuser.com/questions/609985/windows-command-line-utility-to-control-network-bandwidth)
- [How to set download speed limit restriction without using router?](https://superuser.com/questions/469056/how-to-set-download-speed-limit-restriction-without-using-router)

Comment: No the NetLimiter did not destroyed anything, GTA V (DVD Edition) does always take the whole bandwith on any computer. I had the problem before installing NetLimiter. It was the reason why i even installed NetLimiter.